# Bash syntax to convert to lowercase doesn't work in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, lowercase

In Bash, converting the contents of a variable `A` can be achieved by `${A,,}`. In a Makefile, this doesn't work anymore. The following code

```
default:                                                                        
   @for i in a b CCC; do \                                                       
     echo $${i,,}; \                                                             
  done
```

yields the error

```
$ make
/bin/sh: 2: Bad substitution
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

How can you convert a variable in a Makefile to lower case?

Answer (score 3):

The shell used by make is `/bin/sh`, which is a POSIX-compliant shell, not bash.  If you want to write your recipes in bash, then tell make that's what you want:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

Alternatively, write your recipe in standard-compliant ways, like:

```
default:
        @for i in a b CCC; do \
           echo $$i | tr A-Z a-z; \
        done
```

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU Make Standard library](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/) has a function for this (`lc`) written in pure Make.  This lets you do something like this and avoid the shell-specific stuff:

```
default:                                                                        
   @$(foreach i,a b CCC,echo $(call lc,$(i));)
```